# Check whether app updates work without submitting to App Store

Tags: iphone

I have an application already on the store and would like to release an update. Since my app deals with databases and I've had to change some parts of it, I would like to ensure that the update does not affect the existing functionality in any way once the user updates from the App Store.

What I did was this - install the first version of my app on my device. Changed the update's version in info.plist to 1.1 and run it via xcode (and install on my device). But what happens by doing this is some of the changes I made to the XIBs do not show up. It looks as if the app was only half-updated (if you know what I mean)

Is there any way to update an existing app programmatically without having to go through the app store and then find out it could lead to a disaster?!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check your build configuration. Between building the two versions of the app, I would recommend a "Clean All" just to be safe. The process you described works to verify updates. The only other alternative I can come up with is to create Ad-hoc distributions of both versions of your app, and install those.

Comment: Thanks will try creating adhoc builds and see if it works. The build configuration is the same for both apps.